# How much should it cost to change to brake fluid on a ford fiesta 2012 Hatch

Tags: fiesta

How much should it cost to change to brake fluid on a ford fiesta 2012 Hatch, I believe that I may be being overcharged.

Answer (score 1):

It should be about an hours worth of labor plus the cost of the fluid. The labor rates vary depending on your area so the actual monetary amount is hard to pin down.